# Display Username in window title bar

Tags: windows-10, runas, title-bar

I'm doing a lot of runas at work (multiple accounts, poorly managed, but I have no choice).  What I'm looking for is some way to display the user a window is running as in the title bar?  Like I often have 2 SSMS windows open, and no easy way to see which is which.